# replace componentWillRecieiveProps in react 16 in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-16

Says I have this reducer that changed my job status from 'pending' to 'approve',

how to use handle it without using the going to be deprecated `componentWillRecieiveProps`?

I used to do this

```
componentWillRecieiveProps(prevProps, nextProps) {
  if (prevProps.job.status !== nextProps.job.status && nextProps.job.state === 'approved') {
    this.props.history.replace('somewhere')
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shishir Anshuman's comment is correct you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps`, but it's not super obvious how, so I'm going to show you.

This is your original snippet which compares prevProps with nextProps:

```
componentWillRecieiveProps(prevProps, nextProps) {
  if (prevProps.job.status !== nextProps.job.status && nextProps.job.state === 'approved') {
    this.props.history.replace('somewhere')
  }
}
```

What it should look like is something like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.job.status !== nextProps.job.status && nextProps.job.state === 'approved') {
    // return new object to update state
  }
  return null;
}
```

That's based on the assumption that you're storing `job.status` in local state, so your component's construction would need to look something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    job: props.job,
  };
}
```

Although given I don't have full visibility of your data structure I would probably store the `job.status` in local state as boolean called `jobStatus`, then only interrogate `this.props.job` object in my render when `this.state.jobStatus` is true.

If you do that then your `getDerivedStateFromProps` would look like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.jobStatus !== nextProps.job.status && nextProps.job.state === 'approved') {
    // return new object to update state
  }
  return null;
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

As @Patrick Hund pointed out in the comments I missed the static keyword before the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method, this is required.

**Edit 2**

As @markerikson correctly points out in the comment below `getDerivedStateFromProps` should be a pure function and have no side effects, I've updated the snippets to reflect this.

This is the important sentence from the docs I didn't fully grok:

```
It should return an object to update state, or null to indicate that 
the new props do not require any state updates.
```

Comment: good answer, but I think there's one thing missing: as per the documentation, getDerivedStateFromProps needs to be a static method

Comment: This is a bad idea. `getDerivedStateFromProps` _should_ be a pure function, and _not_ have any side effects.  Triggering URL changes absolutely qualifies as a side effect.  The right place for this logic is `componentDidUpdate()`.